# Codeigniter BBCODE or on the fly functionality?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bbcode

I've been looking around for some way to either code up links using bbcode or manually convert a url in a specified message to a link. BBCodes to me are just getting a little old. Although, are still massively heavily used for such things as smileys etc.

I'd be looking to probably do a mixture of the two functionalities.

Can anyone advise on something they use or have used recently for prettifying a messaging system, so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as converting links, Codeigniter's got you covered with the [url helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html):

> **auto_link()**
>
> Automatically turns URLs and email addresses contained in a string
>   into links. Example: $string = auto_link($string);
>
> The second parameter determines whether URLs and emails are converted
>   or just one or the other. Default behavior is both if the parameter is
>   not specified. Email links are encoded as safe_mailto() as shown
>   above.

As for smilies, that's covered as well. There is actually a [smiley helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/smiley_helper.html):

If you give up and want to parse bbcode, here's a helper written by Phil Sturgeon (a lead Codeigniter developer): https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/BBCode-Helper

Comment: Thanks very much for the auto_link reply, muchly appreciated. That helper library looks slightly out of date, but I will surely write something similar myself I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to go with something client side for BBCode interpritation, I've written an [extendible BBCode parser in JavaScript](http://patorjk.com/blog/2011/05/07/extendible-bbcode-parser-in-javascript/).

It has all of the standard BBCode tags, but if your messaging system needed some new tags for certain kinds of URL manipulation they could be easily added. As an example, for a smilies tag you could extend it like this:

```
"smiley": {
    openTag: function(params,content) {
        if (content === ":)") {
            return "<img src='smiley.png'/>";
        } else if (content === ":(") {
            return "<img src='frown.png'/>";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    },
    closeTag: function(params,content) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And then the BBCode would look something like:

```
[smiley]:)[/smiley]
```

And the HTML code it would generate from that would look like this:

```
<img src='smiley.png'/>
```

This might be more work than what you want and you may not want your own custom tags for your messaging system, but I figured I'd mention it just in case.